# Predict value of random variable B if value of random variable A and correlation is known

Tags: probability, correlation, covariance

Intuitively it is clear that if I have two variables $A, B \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma)$ and I have $\rho_{A,B}=-1$, then if some sample $a$ of $A$ is $x$, then some sample $b$ of $B$ is $\mu-x$ because $Var(A+B)=0$.

But I cannot find a general formula for predicting the value of b for different $\rho$ values. How is this "concept" called?

Comment: If you know the cross correlation then you can create $p(A,B)$ via the lifting to the joint Normal distribution. Then you can consider the condition $p(A|B)$.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "predict"? Do you want its expected value? Or its marginal distribution?

Comment: Let's say I have two coins and know (for some reason) that the random variables of the result (head=0, tail=1) are perfectly negatively correlated. This means, if I see head on the first coin, the second coin has always tails. Coming back to my example in the opening post: I want a function that calculates my second outcome based on my first outcome... Knowing the first result and the correlation, it has to be given. Then again, only for $\rho\in\{-1,1\}$?

Comment: And what would be the distribution function for B given the outcome of the first value? (is this called marginal distribution?)

Comment: No, this is called a conditional distribution, and denoted by $p(A\mid B)$, as in AlphaNumeric's comment. By the way, in case your question was directed at @AlphaNumeric, you need to include a ping (as in this sentence) to get them notified. You're being automatically notified of comments here only because this is your question.

Comment: Okay, good to know. @AlphaNumeric any online material to the lifting to the joint normal distribution for this case?

Comment: Look up the definition for the joint Gaussian distribution of 2 variables, specifically the Covariance matrix between them. You'll then have a model for the joint probability and then you can do do the conditional. Wikipedia even has the A|B distribution in terms of the covariance : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Bivariate_case This assumes the joint is Gaussian, the marginals are what you're given. In general you cannot know the value of one random variable given the value of the other, only in extremal cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the sense of "predict" that you explicated in a comment, this is not possible. Unless the correlation is $\pm1$, the value of one variable does not determine the value of the other.

Comment: I see, so this is a special case. Actually, this makes sense but hard to grasp intuitively for me right now. Anyways, thank you!

Comment: @IceFire: Perhaps it's easiest to grasp intuitively in the case where $A$ and $B$ are independent. Then $\rho=0$, and knowing the value of $A$ tells you nothing at all about the value of $B$.

Comment: This is also quite clear. But all $\rho \in (-1,0)\cup (0,1)$ are questionable to me

Comment: @IceFire: Consider $A$ and $C$ independent and $B=\lambda A+(1-\lambda)C$. Then $\rho$ varies from $0$ to $1$ as $\lambda$ varies from $0$ to $1$, and it's clear that the value of $A$ doesn't determine the value of $B$ unless $\lambda=\rho=1$.

Comment: Thanks, this makes it clearer!